# How to stop inputA from changing?

Tags: javascript

so how can i make inputA and inputB have different numbers?
right now inputA is the same as inputB
‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎

```
const numbers = document.querySelectorAll(".numbers");
numbers.forEach((number) => {
  number.addEventListener("click", () => {
    display.textContent += number.innerHTML;
    inputA = display.textContent;
    console.log(inputA + "a")
  });
});

const functions = document.querySelectorAll(".func");
functions.forEach((fnction) => {
  fnction.addEventListener("click", () => {
    display.textContent = "";
    operatorInput = fnction.innerHTML;
    console.log(operatorInput)

    
      numbers.forEach((number) => {
      number.addEventListener("click", () => {
        
        inputB = display.textContent;
        console.log(inputB + "b");
      });
    });

  })
})
```

Comment: Post a [mcve] please

Comment: It is difficult to say anything for definite without the HTML. One thing I noticed already is that you attach two click-event-handlers to both input fields. For this reason the two input fields will always be treated in the same way and cannot have a differing content.

Comment: how can I attach the second eventlistener only to the inputB?

Comment: Where does the `display` object come from, inside the first EventListener callback?

Comment: @kyopa don't iterate through your entire NodeList - just pick the one you want, like with an #id selector maybe.

Comment: its an HTML class

Comment: It would help if you make a small codepen of what you're trying to do, then we can see your html and the rest of your variables.

Answer (score 0):

First of all document.querySelectorAll doesnt return array.
The proper usage is:

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(selector)).forEach...
```

Please check the reference https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

You dont declare variables inputA and inputA (let inputA, let inputB).
What's more, display.textContent in case B is equal to the display.textcontent from the case A.
Because it's the same element. Despite you attempt to clear textContent in the upperscope (case B) it has no effect.

Comment: i do declare the variables i just didnt include it here.

Comment: You should modify display.textContent in case B or create one more element for example

Comment: i just tried ```displayB.textcontent``` on the inputB and it still doesnt work

Comment: Show your HTML please

Comment: all the numbers in my HTML both have a class of ```numbers``` and ```numbersB``` the display element also has classes ```display``` and ```displayB```

Comment: You click a number and what this number to be different in inputA and inputB

Comment: @kyopa — "all the numbers in my HTML both have a class of" ... but you don't _show_ any of that in your question, or "i do declare the variables i just didnt include it here" — You really have to include enough to demonstrate the problem. As j08691 commented (on the question) you've really got to post a minimal **reproducible** example.